# order of sql join statement

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have some pieces are not clear to me:

```
select Student.sID, sName, GPA, Apply.cName, enrollment
from Student, College, Apply
where Apply.sID = Student.sID and Apply.cName = College.cName;
```

So in this statement cross product occur before the join condition , or they are done at the same time , i mean we compare the sid , then we form the table , or we make the tables "crossed product" then we make the condition  ?

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

"then we form the table " is correct. Nothing wrong with your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The query optimizer will always try to make a plan that is optimized. So, most likely, it should not determine the cross-product first and then apply the WHERE clause; but, the query optimizer may choose to get the cross product first if the cross join has very few records and doing so ends up being less expensive.

So, the only way you can determine how `mysql` is handling this query is by looking at the query plan, which you can get by using EXPLAIN command as below.

**Get Query Optimizer's Plan for your query**

```
EXPLAIN select Student.sID, sName, GPA, Apply.cName, enrollment
from Student, College, Apply
where Apply.sID = Student.sID and Apply.cName = College.cName;
```

Also, you might find the following useful, which is from MySql docs at [EXPLAIN statement in MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html)

> When you precede a SELECT statement with the keyword EXPLAIN, MySQL displays information from the optimizer about the statement execution plan. That is, MySQL explains how it would process the statement, including information about how tables are joined and in which order. For information about using EXPLAIN to obtain execution plan information, see Section 8.8.2, “EXPLAIN Output Format”.